# How to read columns from different files and plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plot

I have data of concentrations for every day of year 2005 until 2018. I want to read three columns of three different files and combine them into one, so I can plot them.

Data:file 1

```
time, mean_OMNO2d_003_ColumnAmountNO2CloudScreened
2005-01-01,-1.267651e+30
2005-01-02,4.90778397e+15
...
2018-12-31,-1.267651e+30
```

Data:file 2

```
time, OMNO2d_003_ColumnAmountNO2TropCloudScreened
2005-01-01,-1.267651e+30
2005-01-02,3.07444147e+15
...
```

Data:file 3

```
time, OMSO2e_003_ColumnAmountSO2_PBL
2005-01-01,-1.267651e+30
2005-01-02,-0.0144000314
...
```

I want to plot `time` and `mean_OMNO2d_003_ColumnAmountNO2CloudScreened`, `OMNO2d_003_ColumnAmountNO2TropCloudScreened`, `OMSO2e_003_ColumnAmountSO2_PBL` into one graph.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

file_list = glob.glob('*.csv')

no= []
no2=[]
so2=[]


for f in file_list:
    df= pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=8, parse_dates =['time'], index_col ='time')
    df.columns=['no','no2','so2']
    no.append([df["no"]])
    no2.append([df["no2"]])
    so2.append([df["so2"]])
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Please format the question correctly and put example strings instead of long gibberish strings. And the expected output. Did you take a look at `pd.concat`?

Answer (score 0):

This is very doable. I had a similar problem with 3 files all in one plot. My understanding is that you want to compare levels of NO, NO2, and SO2, that each column is in comparable order, and that you want to compare across rows. If you are ok with importing matplotlib and numpy, something like this may work for you:

```
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib as plt

 NO = np.asarray(df["no1"])
 NO2 = np.asarray(df["no2"]))
 SO2 = np.asarray(df["so2"))
 timestamp = np.asarray(df["your_time_stamp"])
 plt.plot(timestamp, NO)
 plt.plot(timestamp, NO2)
 plt.plot(timestamp, SO2)
 plt.savefig(name_of_plot)
```

This will need some adjusting for your specific data frame, but I hope you see what I am getting at!